# Is there a word for four times as much, analogous to once, twice, and thrice?

Tags: single-word-requests, recurring-events

Is there a word for 'four times as much', analogous to *once*, *twice*, and *thrice*?

Comment: The next one in the series would have to be *quince*, right? :)

Comment: I don't care if it's not a word, I'm going to start using "frice" just to weird people out.

Comment: I hereby propose that henceforth "quadrice" and "quince" shall mean four and five times, respectively! "He struck me not twice, not thrice, but quadrice!" "How ghastly! At least he didst not strike thee quince!" "Nay not at that moment, but later in the day he did!"

Comment: Quince is already a fruit. But good thing he didn't throw a quince at you.

Comment: Actually, since *once*, *twice*, and *thrice* come from *one*, *two*, and *three* plus the Old English genitive ending *-es* (the source of the apostrophe-s for possessive), the correct words would be more along the lines of *fource*, *fifce* / *fivce*, *sice*, *sevence*, *eightce*, *nince*, *tence*, etc.

Comment: There is a charming book by Alastair Reid, called *Ounce, Dice, Trice* in which (among many other kinds of wordplay) he creates novel numbering systems. From memory, one is "ounce, dice, trice, quartz, quince, sago, serpent, oculist, novelist, dentist".

Comment: Why was sago afraid of the serpent? Cause serpent oculist novelist!! Oh wait, darn...

Comment: @ Jon Purdy: That would be a nice answer, if "one" in Old English was "on" or even "one"; however, to my admittedly limited knowledge of O.E., "one" is án, and "once" is ánes. "two" is twá; "twice," twiwa.

Comment: The ones that sound best among these are, in my opinion, _fource_ (as per Jon Purdy's comment), _quince_ (as per Coaudiu's). After that, _sice_ and _eightce_ don't sound very good, but _sevence_, _nince_, _tence_ I like.

Comment: Adding -ce to the Anglo Saxon seems to be the rule: an+ce, twa+ce, thri+ce, so since we're speculating... per @JonPurdy, looks like '-ce' becomes a suffix used exactly like '-th' but with irregulars where it's awkward to say: feower+ce is easy '*fource', fif+ce perhaps pronounced '*fiss' since 'f' and 's' sounds seem likely to merge ('fifth' is already '*fith' in causal speech), siex+ce or syx+ce with 's' and 'x' merging almost certainly pronounced '*siss' perhaps spelled '*sice', seofon+ce '*sevence', eahta+ce '*eightce' is easily pronounced 'ates', nigon+ce '*ninece', tien+ce 'tence'.

Comment: @android.weasel: "Fifce he smote me with his axe, eightce with his hammer, yet tence did I with my godly words smite him, and there the demon fell, never to rise again!" I like it - good stuff!

Comment: @JonPurdy I didn't notice your Saxon 'twice' tuwa/twiwa comment and I can't find a Saxon 'thrice' from my extensive 30 seconds of websearching. So no 'real' etymology sadly, but the hypothetical game was fun.

Comment: Use the fource!

Comment: @Claudiu my 6 year old was talking about number of times he did things and he said - quatrice, quintrice etc. I didn't think these were real words but seemed legit based on the logic, so googled and reached here. His understanding appears to match your statement 

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not according to the [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/123):

> These three are the only words of their type, and no further terms in the series have ever existed.

Comment: Way to drop the ball, English.

Comment: The link is dead. A new link is here: https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-comes-after-once-twice-thrice

Answer (score 10):

No, [there isn't](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/123).

> What comes after once, twice, thrice?
>
> Nothing! These three are the only words of their type, and no further terms in the series have ever existed.

Comment: I would quote what that page says, just in case the link goes dead.

Comment: @RegDwight so would Dusty :)

Comment: The link is dead. A new link is here: https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-comes-after-once-twice-thrice