# What's the word for "twelvely"?

Tags: meaning

If something is nested twice, it's "double nested".
If something is nested three times, it's "triple nested".
If something is nested twelve times, it's ... What? "Dodecly nested?"

Edit: Apparently, according to [websters-online-dictionary.com](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.com/definitions/twelvely) as quoted below, the adverbial form of *twelve* actually is "twelvely", but that form is virtually never used. Is there one that is used?

> 1. Virtually never used adverbial inflection of the adjective twelve.

Comment: Generally, when you get above quadruply, any further words are derived and not in standard usage.  Note your examples are different forms of the word, *double* and *triple*, are not the same as *dodecly*, that would be *doubly*, *triply*.

Comment: Ah I suppose my first two examples are adjectives not adverbs. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: _Twelvely_ may be an attention-getter, but would not be a form for normal use, just as we would not use _twoly, threely, fourly,_ etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to form single, double, triple… and uni-, bi-, tri-… words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/how-to-form-single-double-triple-and-uni-bi-tri-words)

Comment: I have to put in my vote for *[twelvce](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/once-twice-thrice-frice)*. Once-nested, twice-nested, twelvce-nested.

Comment: Looking at google Ngrams, the most common terms for *n-tuply* seem to go *... quadruply, quintuply, sextuply, sevenly, eightly, ninely, tenly, ...* These were much more common two centuries ago, but even then anything above ten was extremely rare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Nested twelve times* is the clearest, most unambiguous, and most common way to say this. You could also say *nested twelvefold*—**twelvely*, however, does not appear in the OED and I would not recommend using it.

Comment: The OED attests **duodecuple** as an adjective meaning twelvefold, and gives this citation: “1727 Arbuthnot *Coins* (J.), ― To establish the duodecuple proportion.” However, “duodecuply nested” just doesn’t roll off the tongue at all so smoothly as “triply nested” does.

Comment: Or possibly 'nested twelve *deep*'?

Answer (score 6):

Is it programming specific or ...?
if not, i'd recommand [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), as :

Single (1) (also: singleton, sole, only, etc.)
Double (2) (also: pair, twice)
Triple (3) (also: triplet, treble, thrice, threesome, troika, trio)
Quadruple (4)
Quintuple or Pentuple (5)
Sextuple or Hextuple (6)
Septuple (7)
Octuple (8)
Nonuple (9)
Decuple (10)
Hendecuple or Undecuple (11)
Duodecuple (12)
Centuple (100)

Comment: In this case, it is. Someone has 12 nested loops. (Yes I told him it's a bad idea!)

Comment: @glowcoder: Please tell me that program is not running a nuclear power plant or an air traffic control system.

Comment: @James It's actually for a test scenario. There are 12 options to run, (OS, Database type, etc) and wants to run through each combination. I estimate it to take at least 88 thousand server-hours to test, and that's a very conservative estimate!

Answer (score 2):

There is no word that is commonly used for this, although you can construct such terms from the standard affixes (as shown [here](http://www.sandiegoradionews.com/83pages/831300.htm)).  Using this approach, one could say "duodecatuply nested".  (Note that the form should be an adverb, like *triply*, rather than an adjective like *triple*.)

However, for clarity one should avoid such constructed words and use a more understandable word sequence such as *nested twelve times*.

Comment: I don't think "duodecatuply" is correctly formed. The dictionaries I checked show "duodecuple" as the word, without any "-at-" in it.