# thrice, twice, once, *zeroce?

Tags: single-word-requests

In similarity to this question:
[Is there a word for four times as much, analogous to once, twice, and thrice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/once-twice-thrice-frice)

What are some words that indicate 'zero times' ?

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for a word that clearly states a zero-time occurrence. Not a simple negation.

Comment: -1 because the answer to the question you linked also has the answer to this question.

Comment: why is everyone voting this question down?

Comment: As per the comment by MrHen, your answer is in that question you linked. There are no other terms in the series "once, twice, thrice" besides the ones listed.

Comment: @simchona - While I can see that the "frice" question _does_ say that there are no other terms in the series, it is not explicit about the lack of a zero equivalent, as that thread was concentrating more on the sequence _after_ thrice, rather than _before_ once. Picky, I know, but _I_ actually came to this thread looking for a zero equivalent as I felt that the answer wasn't definitive in the "frice" thread. Maybe it needs to be made clearer (for us dumbasses) in the "frice" thread. :-)

Comment: If you're looking for a word that actually fits the pattern of of "once, twice, thrice", you could always just make up "nonce" (rhymes with "once") as a nonce (rhymes with "haunts") word. It would probably be better to just say "never" or "no times", or even just say it didn't happen, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was done once.
It was done twice.
It was done never.
It was never done.

Answer (score 9):

**There is no English word that means "zero times."** The **only** words which mean "{number} times" in English are *once*, *twice*, and *thrice*.

However, there are many ways to *express* that an action has been done zero times (including those given in the other answers), for example, saying, "It was done **zero times**."

Comment: What about *twofold* and *threefold*?

Comment: @whoabackoff "-fold" doesn't mean "{number} times", but rather "times {number}" (which is *significantly* different in meaning) and can generally only be used in comparisons, not occurrences.

Comment: And there's "a shield of threefold bronze" which is neither comparison nor occurrence (come to think of it, it may be a description rather than an idiom)

Answer (score 5):

The typical way to say this is to simply negate the action. For the example of "It was done once/twice/thrice", one would say "it was not done." Other than that, there is no equivalent to once/twice/thrice for anything other than 1, 2, 3.

Comment: This answer isn't useful since it can only be applied with 'done'. What about 'I asked once/twice/thrice'?

Comment: "I did not ask." You should be able to extrapolate this to other verbs. The answer is, "There is no such word for 0."

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question. You're simply negating the verb. I'm looking for an answer that clearly states 'ZERO times'.

Comment: There isn't one, other than saying "zero times" or "I did not do it" or "it was not done." There is no equivalent to once/twice/thrice other than those specific three words.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a philosophical problem, not linguistic. "It was done zero times" is just a clumsy way of saying "it was not done."  So asking for a word that means one and not the other is self-defeating.

(This is a common mistake by computer programmers, since "a variable set to zero" is not the same as "a variable not defined".  But reality does not work like that.)

Answer (score 2):

Once, twice, thrice? Perhaps the answer is **Never** found. Not Ever.

So we still have the negation, but it's applied to the time Ever, not the verb.