# I've said it once, I've said it twice, I've said it a thousand times

Tags: etymology, numbers, triple-thrice, recurring-events

I had a student moaning because I insisted he say *twice* and not "two times". And he asked "But why?" to which I replied, "Because that's how you say it!"

However on reflection, his question was a valid one.

In Latin there doesn't appear to be any discernible pattern

> - once is *semel*
> - twice is *bis*
> - thrice is *ter*
> - four times is *quater*
> - five times is *quinquies*

but in German the suffix **-mal** is used,

> - once is *einmal*
> - twice is *zweimal*
> - thrice is *dreimal*
> - four times is *viermal*

In French the term **fois** is repeated

> - once is *une fois*
> - twice is *deux fois*
> - thrice is *trois fois*
> - four times is *quatre fois*

In Italian the noun **volta** (s) **volte** (p) is used

> - once is *una volta*
> - twice is *due volte*
> - thrice is *tre volte*
> - four times is *quattro volte*

In Spanish **veces** is repeated

> - once is *una vez*
> - twice is *dos veces*
> - thrice is *tres veces*
> - four times is *cuatro veces*

And all the following languages follow the same pattern.  In Danish it's **gange**; in Norwegian **ganger**; in Polish **raz** and **razy**; Portuguese has **vez** and **vezes**; and Welsh uses **waith** and **gwaith**.

---

### Questions

- So why does the English language have three different words for "one time", "two times" and "three times"?
- Beyond a shadow of a doubt the English *thrice* is doomed to exile if not extinction; will *twice* suffer the same fate? For instance, many Italian speakers learning English do say "two times"—*for them* it makes more sense.

**Clarification**:
I am not suggesting that *twice* is old fashioned, unnecessary or— heaven forbid—nonsensical. But considering the history of *thrice*, it is *possible*  that sometime in the future, native speakers  will look back fondly on *twice* as being quaint and quite rare. My second question is in fact asking if there are signs of this happening now.

---

Related Questions:
[Why has the word “thrice” fallen out of common usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146043/why-has-the-word-thrice-fallen-out-of-common-usage?rq=1)
[Twice vs Two Times](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171833/twice-vs-two-times?lq=1)
[Is there a word for four times as much, analogous to once, twice, and thrice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/is-there-a-word-for-four-times-as-much-analogous-to-once-twice-and-thrice)

Comment: +1, Good question. I'm so depressed, Mari-Lou. First, "thrice", now, "twice"! I've loved those words.

Comment: Small niggle: the Danish is _gange_ (_ganges_ is the possessive plural), and the Welsh is [_gwaith_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gwaith) (lenited after certain numerals—so it’s _un waith_ ‘one time’ and _dwy waith_ ‘two times’, but _tair gwaith_ ‘three times’ and _pedair gwaith_ ‘four times’, etc.).

Comment: In most language, the low numbers have other uses besides counting. In Romance and Germanic languages, `1` is also an indefinite article, for instance. And singular and plural is standard. For `2`, couples, twins, etc. are also standard; so we have the dual number in PIE, for instance, plus words like _both, twice, pair,_ etc. Also normal to have special dual terms. Three is where the breaking point comes; English has rare _thrice_, but that's a pedants word any more. It gets a laugh in _A Funny Thing Happened On The Way To The Forum_ -- "He raped Thrace thrice!" But that's it for `3`.

Comment: Let's not forget [_frice_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frice) :)

Comment: (Also, just took the liberty of editing your Latin number 1 adverb—it’s _semel_, not _iterum_, which means ‘again, a second time’.)

Comment: Oh, Latin a pattern — eventually: *Primo pro nummata vini; 
ex hac bibunt libertini; 
semel bibunt pro captivis, 
post haec bibunt ter pro vivis, 
quater pro Christianis cunctis, 
quinquies pro fidelibus defunctis, 
sexies pro sororibus vanis, 
septies pro militibus silvanis. 
octies pro fratribus perversis, 
nonies pro monachis dispersis, 
decies pro navigantibus, 
undecies pro discordantibus, 
duodecies pro paenitentibus, 
tredecies pro iter agentibus.*

Comment: You can't fool me: I've been to Italy and I know how Romans count: I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, XI, XII. It's on all the clocks. Some of those are really hard to say, too, like "I-I-I"! :-)

Comment: I think you're underestimating English while giving too much credit to others. Actually on(e)-ce, tw(o)-ce, thr(ee)-ce is IMHO pretty solid pattern (for English) and coming from inflectional language they don't seem like 3 different words to me. Your Polish example is wrong, as "raz" is special word meaning "one time" and there are no others to denote more times. Except for constructed ones: jednokrotnie, dwukrotnie, trzykrotnie. Just as once, twice, thrice : )

Comment: @Agent_L I apologize for the mistake concerning Polish, I limited myself to using Google and saw that *raz* was indeed used one time and then *razy* was repeated for *twice/two times* *thrice/three times* etc. Thank you for pointing out that discrepancy! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nothing to apologize for! Indeed you can say `raz` or `jeden raz` for "one time", and `dwa razy` for "two times" but in this context `raz` works just like any other countable item.

Comment: @MartinKrzywinski It depends on the level of the student. For an advanced student, recommending "twice" instead of "two times" is excellent advice on idiomatic usage: in my experience, native speakers very rarely say "two times". For a beginner, it is perhaps overly pedandic to *insist* on "twice", since "two times" is 100% comprehensible.

Comment: Your question should probably be worded as a question. I suggest the question in your question's detail: Why does the English language have three different words for "one time", "two times" and "three times"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was talking about the header, which I clicked out of curiosity but it didn't tell me what the question was about. I notice the references to the content of the question now, which is clever but probably confusing without looking into the question's detail.

Comment: I opted for an eye catching title over a more precise one. A little naughty of me, but the question title is not completely divorced. The "But why?" in the introduction can be interpreted as asking: *"Why should I say "twice" instead of "two times"?"* OR *"Why does English have the term "twice" instead of "two times"?"* It's a little ambiguous, I admit.

Comment: *No language makes perfect sense.* — John McWhorter

Comment: What exactly is the question? Re-reading multiple times, I still can't find the primary question here. Any answer to 'why' here is going to be purely speculative. The most correct answer to your student though is 'If you use "two times" instead of twice, you'll sound weird.'

Comment: @Mitch I disagree that saying "two times" will sound weird. The student will be clearly understood, by AmEng speakers and non. My primary concern is that he understands the pronunciation of twice, which for some Italians is problematic due to first language interference, and secondly that he realizes that *once*, *twice* and THEN *three times* are most commonly used.

Comment: Mari-LouA, 1) thanks for making explicit. 2) 'Why' is always a hard question and often devolves into unsatisfying description. 3) being understood and sounding weird vs idiomatic are not the same. Language is not a logical prescription like a programming language. It never started from a logical set of tables with all the entries filled in nicely.

Comment: While *twice* may be more usual than *two times*, the reverse is the case with *thrice* and *three times*.

Comment: There is actually a pattern to the Latin numbers, it's just been completely obscured by regular sound changes in prehistoric Latin. _Semel_ is of course irregular, but the others basically add _-(ie)s_ to what was originally the zero-grade of their stem: _bis_ comes from /dwis/ < stem /dwoi-, dwei-/ (cf. _duō_); _ter_ is from /tr̥s/ < /tris/ < stem /trei-/ (cf. _trēs_ < _treies_); _quater_ is from /kwatwr̥s/ < stem /kwatuor-/ (cf. _quattuor_); and the rest basically just add _-ies_ to the stem (_quinqu-_, _sex-_, _sept-_, _oct-_, _nōn-_, _dec-_, etc.).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "prehistoric" Latin?! Thanks for pointing out the suffix *-ies* is added to ordinals after the number *quater*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, at some point between Proto-Italic and the earliest attested Latin texts. ‘Prehistoric’ with history referring to actual attestations. :-)

Comment: Also related: [How common is “thrice”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5580)

Comment: [Love me two times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVez4RS7IJw).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason English has three different words for those is because English has three different words for 1, 2, and 3. It’s like why we have three different words for *sixth, eighth, and twelfth*: there’s a suffix here used with regular numbers.

The difference is that instead of *‑th* for ordinals, it’s *‑ce* for adverbials, and you just aren't recognizing that *‑ce* adverbs things — or at least, that it adverbed them **once** upon a time.

That’s because *‑es* was a genitive adverbial suffix in Old English.  You can see its remains in all kinds of adverbs that are today spelled with an *‑s* at the end.

Note that genitive nouns also end in *‑s*. The difference is that making genitive nouns (well, and noun phrases with a clitic *‑’s*) is still productive.  However, making adverbials this way no longer is so, although now and then people coin new ones along existing models by analogy.

Other *‑s* examples of adverbs made like *once, twice, thrice* include such words as *afterwards, backwards, besides, betimes, forwards, hereabouts, needs, nowheres, nights, nowadays, sideways, thereabouts, towards, unawares* — with plenty more where those came from.  As Janus mentions in comments, there is also a broad set of those which gained a parasitic (=inorganic, non-etymological) final *‑t* on top of their *‑es/‑s*, such as *acrost, against, amidst, amongst, betwixt, gainst, whilst*.

Because we made adverbs out of things by adding *‑es* (later *‑s*) all the time, it was the natural way to make an adverbial out of the numbers. The word *nonce* has the same origin, although that’s used for a noun not an adverb.  In Old English, the word for modern *once* was *ænes* or *enes*, genitive forms coming directly from the Old English word for *one*, which was *án*.

By the way, the Old English word *án* that gave birth to modern *one* and *once* also gave us the indefinite articles *a, an*. But when Old English speakers said *ænes* (again, that was their word for *once*), it had two different syllables. That situation was not to last, however, and this led to orthographic changes.

Middle English picked up *twice* and *thrice* by the same construction, although with differing spelling and pronunciation than we use today. Then around 1500, as *ones* became monosyllabic, it began to be spelled *-ce* to indicate the lack of voicing — and, for the cases of *twice* and *thrice*, to indicate a change in character of the preceding vowel.

So what’s going on is that you no longer recognize this fossilized morpheme as meaningful.  It means exactly the same thing as those other free morphemes you mention in other tongues.

And no: *twice* isn't going away. Neither are *twin, both, halve,* or *double*. *Twain* might someday be, though, moving into literary use not bar talk.  As for your Italian learners, I strongly advise against saying “two times”; it does not sound right to this native ear.  Indeed, the OED specifically reports that *twice* is:

> In all senses now the regular substitute for the phrase *two times*

On the other hand, *tuppence* and *thruppence* are hardly worth a *farthing* today, eh? :-)

Comment: [Depends on the native speaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Times) ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gee, and here I thought you were here to remind people of *þrisvar*. :)

Comment: And what were "four times" and "five times" in Old and Middle English? If they too had the -es/s suffix, when did the term *time/s* take over?

Comment: I was going to comment about what a *concise* summary of the situation you've given. But it's a bit *too* concise for me. The only class of "adverbs ending in **s**" I can think of offhand are [dialectal?] forms like *anyways, somewheres*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  *always* and *sometimes* came to my mind, and then I got stuck :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: According to _OED_,  the usual word in Old English and early Middle English is _sithe_. (earliest recorded forms are _siða_ and _sið_). In Middle English, it turned into _tymes_. And then _times_.

Comment: {Sorry I didn't realie this A answers ML's first question, at the bottom of the OP.}

Comment: @FumbleFingers A lot of them have been obscured later on by adding an unetymological _-t_ (probably taken over from the superlatives in _-est_): _against_, _amongst_, _betwixt_, _whilst_, etc. But there are others that still retain just _-s_, like _besides_ and the variants in _-wards_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: [Indeed it does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Me_Two_Times).

Comment: Or, for that matter, why we have "eleven" and "twelve" instead of a hypothetical "oneteen, twoteen" (I assume derived from some old english equivalent of "X and ten")

Comment: Thank you for a very informative and readable answer, which made a lot of sense :)

Comment: @MariLouA You might enjoy King James's [*thrice-happy peace*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/231582/2085). ;-)

Answer (score 20):

> **So why does the English language have three different words for "one time", "two times" and "three times"?**

In other words, why do *one time*, *two times* and *three times* have single words (*once, twice, thrice*) but *four times*, *five times* etc. don't have?

Simple answer is; *one time*, *two times* and *three times* were frequently used—as lower numbers like *one , two and three* tend to be used more frequently—and turned into one word naturally.

From a linguistic standpoint, the adverbial use of the genitive of *one* was lexicalized and extended to *two* and *three*. The morphological formation involved in this process is [fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_morphology#Fusion).

The usual word for this sense of *times* in Old English and early Middle English is *sithe*. (probably a softer pronunciation of *tide*)

> <sub>In Old English the case is either the instrumental, or the accusative governed by a prep. The instr. pl. *síðum* became Middle English *sīðen*, and finally assumed the same form as the sing. In place of a numeral, an adj. or adv. might be used, as in *eft-sith(es)* *eft adv.* Compounds, *fele-sithe(s) fele adj.*, and *oftsithes adv.*). With the Scottish forms (δ) cf. modern North Frisian *-sis*, as in *twasis* twice, *manningsis* many times.</sub>

For example, *OED* lists the earliest phrases as *æne siða* and *ænne sið* for *one time*:

> - c825   *Vesp. Psalter* lxi. 12   **Æne siða** spreocende wes God.
> - OE   *Beowulf* 1579   Oftor micle ðonne on **ænne sið**.

Then, we can see that it starts forming into a single word (*ænes, anes, ones*) and eventually becomes what we call *once* today:

> - OE   *Lambeth Psalter* lxxxviii. 36   Semel iuraui in sancto meo : **ænes** ic swor on minum halgan.
> - ?c1200   *Ormulum (Burchfield transcript)* l. 1078   Þatt wass aȝȝ **æness** o þe ȝer.
> - a1225  (▸?a1200)    *MS Trin. Cambr. in R. Morris Old Eng. Homilies* (1873) 2nd Ser. 109 (MED),   The sunne..arist **anes** a dai.
> - a1325  (▸c1250)    *Gen. & Exod.* (1968) l. 3288   Ilke dai..**Ones** he ðor it sungen rigt.

But then, why it is changing back to two separate words (*thrice* > *three times*)? This is related to the typological shift in the language from synthetic to analytic by language historians. [Synthetic languages have a high morpheme-per-word ratio and analytic languages have a low morpheme-per-ratio]

Sources:

- *[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202100?rskey=uk6VdD&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)*
- *Naturalness and Markedness* by Henning Andersen / [academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/808988/2008._Naturalness_and_Markedness_)
- *Naturalness and Iconicity in Language* edited by Klaas Willems, Ludovic De Cuypere
- *Wikipedia* - *[Lexicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicalization)*, *[Synthetic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language)*, *[Distributed Morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_morphology#Fusion)*

---

> **Beyond a shadow of a doubt the English thrice is doomed to exile if not extinction, is twice suffering the same fate? For instance, many Italian learners do say "two times"—for them it makes more sense.**

Language is changing but morphological changes or formations slowed down in Modern English. *Twice* might seem like changing into *two times* but it still sounds more natural in most contexts and it is more common; however *two times* is gaining usage in informal speech mainly.

*Twice* wins the usual *[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice%2Ctwo%20times&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20times%3B%2Cc0)* battle obviously but there is, of course, more to it. Below is an analysis and comparison of *twice* and *two times* based on selected British and American newspapers (from the book *One Language, Two Grammars?: Differences Between British and American English* edited by Günter Rohdenburg, Julia Schlüter).

While *once* is firmly established and *thrice* has been generally ousted by the more regular (analytic) *three times*, there seems to be a competition between still-frequent (synthetic) adverb *twice* and *two times*. <sup>(rephrased)</sup>

[image]

> The data in the figure show the rate of occurrence of two items in certain high-frequency collocations.<sup>7</sup> Though *twice* is still well entrenched here, it is used more sparingly in AmE than BrE. The frequencies of *two times* contract in the reverse direction. This suggests that there might be a compensatory relationship between the two adverbs, with AmE favoring the more regular option.<sup>8</sup>
>
> <sub><sup>7</sup> The environments searched includes *twice/two times as much/often/large*, etc. *twice/two times the size/length/speed*, etc. and *twice/two times a day/week/year*, etc.
>
>   <sup>8</sup> The case of special temporal adverb *twice* has a (distant) parallel in the time expression *fortnight* and the derived adjective/adverb *fortnightly*. Here again, even the formal AmE makes much less use of the synthetic and more opaque term: in *The Washington Times*,*forthnight(ly)* occurs merely 1:5 times pmw, while in the British *Times* it has a frequency of 28.4 pmw.</sub>

*OED* is bold enough to say the below but it might not be considering all the relevant data:

> ***two times*** as advb. phr. (expressing repetition or multiplication) is now used only with a demonstrative or defining word; otherwise *twice* is substituted
>
> - 1574   E. Hellowes tr. A. de Guevara *Familiar Epist.* 174   Two times I haue moued the Cardinall Tortosa in your busines.
> - 1916   *N.E.D.* at *Two*,   Mod. I have known it happen two separate times. I called upon him three times, but saw him only once; the other two times he was away.

Comment: You should sleep in the middle of the night!!:))

Comment: Google NGrams backs you up [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one%2Ctwo%2Cthree%2Cfour%2Cfive%2Csix%2Cseven%2Ceight%2Cnine%2Cten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cten%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This is a *good* answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to thoroughly research your answer"

Comment: The Ngrams for 'two times' will include noise such as 'there were one or two times' and 'two times table'. But far worse is the statement 'two times [may be] turning into a serious competitor for the still-frequent (synthetic) adverb twice' when it comprises less than 1% of even the US data.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good points about the "noise" aspect of Ngrams, they can give false results. The bar graph is enlightening until you notice the 0.25 number and compare it to 25.0. I had missed that bit, so thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks. What do you suggest for Ngram related statement? I already mentioned that there is more to it (updated with some new wording). I omitted "serious" and rephrased that statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use Ngrams at all here. The noise is hard to estimate. Even so, the US ratio of tokens for 'twice' to 'two times' shows that the latter is at most 1% of the former. Perhaps looking up individual instances of 'two times' on a raw Google search and discounting false positives (where the _twice_ sense is not intended) would give a truer picture. But there are a lot of examples (eg firms, song titles) that it might be hard to estimate the relevance of even here.

Comment: Ermanen, the second OED entry analyzed things wrong. It _should_ be 'two times' because it is using it as a noun. Twice would be wrong here.

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry, I couldn't see, which part? Is it an error in OED?

Comment: Your very last reference: "1916 N.E.D. at Two, Mod. I have known it happen two separate times. I called upon him three times, but saw him only once; the other two times he was away." 'The other two times' is a noun phrase, 'the other twice' doesn't work.

Comment: @Mitch: Should we warn OED then? :)

Comment: OED is the bestest dictionary of all (of English). Which is not to say that there might be... um... infelicities. Is there a 'suggestions' page at oed.com?

Comment: Under [Contact us](http://public.oed.com/contact-us/) section, there is "Content Comment" link that you can send an e-mail through.

Comment: I think you mean *the following*, not *the below*, right?

Answer (score 8):

Jim Morisson would have sounded funny singing 'Love me twice baby, love twice today, love me twice girl ..."

But then, Lennon and McCartney's "One after 909" works better with "Move over once, move over twice, c'mon baby don't you be cold as ice," because "two times" does not rhyme with "ice."

But while we are asked to "Knock three times" on the ceiling, we should knock "twice on the pipes" if the answer is no.

It's a matter of style, rather than correct grammar. While brevity is desirable, the lengthier "two times" has its place if it serves to emphasize or enhance the cadence.

And as an example of when one should say "two times" rather than "twice", we would say "The last two times ..." rather than "The last twice ..."

Comment: I think the Doors were one of the best bands in the 60s but song lyrics are not an infallible guideline as to *how* English should be spoken. I'm not saying there is only one way, that there aren't alternatives, but the Doors phrase "love me two times babe" has exactly the same meaning as  "love me twice babe", which by the way sounds cool in a song but less so in speech.

Comment: ML .. song lyrics are an **absolutely infallible** guideline to which words are and are not commonplace, in the most up-to-the minute topical sense. "Guideline" is not even the right word to use - they literally define, are, popular usage. There's almost literally nothing else: they are the gold standard.

Comment: I like this answer but it doesn't explain why English needs it and other languages don't. There is no need in rythm in Danish or German?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yes and no; like all poetry, lyrics suffer a certain degree of distortion from the need to fit some desired pattern. So comparing possible phrasings in a song to determine the wider comparison is highly dubious; a given phrase may work well in one context but not in another, and neither may be particularly indicative of the actual usage patterns, beyond the bare fact that they do work.

Comment: @Mike The lyrics are: *Love me two times, girl 
One for tomorrow 
One just for today 
Love me two times 
I'm goin' away* So, two times in this context means to make love to somebody twice on the same day! :) The choice of words is dictated by prose, rhyme, number of syllables etc..

Comment: @ Pierre, English is not a language based on need or logical construct. It is an amalgam of languages, and often contains multiple words from various donor languages to serve the same purpose. There are some contextual influences that favor one word over the other in certain instances, but fewer cut and dried rules

Answer (score 2):

(1) Taio Cruz - [Dynamite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vysgv7qVYTo)

(Pop song lyrics are a great pedagogical device in these cases. [Link](http://www.metrolyrics.com/dynamite-lyrics-taio-cruz.html))

The idea that twice is facing extinction seems whacky, look up the plays of that song.

Note that the pop song industry targets the lowest conceivable intelligence and educational demographic market...and indeed targets LCD international English.

(2) "twice" is a commonplace word.  All you have to tell the students is "that is a commonplace word."

(3) "However on reflection, his question was a valid one." No, it's silly. All he or she can possibly do is ask some English speakers if it is a common word. If they all say "sure", then, if he/she disagrees it is bizarre.

(4) Regarding Latin, German etc - the issue would seem to be **irrelevant**, right?  I can see no connection, at all, between etymology and "what words are currently commonplace".

We could trivially list a number of words that are currently very popular (with such and such etymology), and we could trivially list a number of words that are currently not popular (with such and such etymology). Right?

(5) Hence regarding your question... "Is 'twice' heading to extinction?"

As far as I know the only way to answer such questions is (a) demonstrate the word is used in commercial hugely successful pop music industry lyrics or (b) just canvas opinion of native speakers.  I'd say "sure, it's commonplace".

For example, parents often yell at the kids "don't make me ask you twice, damnit!!" It would be very unusual to yell "...two times" "think twice" "i had to run to the office twice today" are all highly natural, common phrases (with the usual caveat that any such claim about "what is common" in language is just an opinion).

Comment: The reason for my posting examples from different European languages was to show that the English language is quite unique in having three single words that appear unrelated to the term *times*. Secondly, I took my student's question seriously 1) I told him that he had to learn *twice* but that *two times* was not wrong (I really don't think it's necessary for me to post the entire dialogue, just the gist) 2) I posted my question on EL&U.

Comment: On the other hand, your answer is border-close to being patronizing, and doesn't take into account the influence non-native speakers have on molding and modifying English, look at the differences between Indian English, American English, Australian English and British English. First language interference has an impact on how English is spoken today. 3) My **actual** question are in fact TWO, but you chose to dismiss the first one.

Comment: patronizing?!  once bitten, twice shy.  I'm sorry it must be one of those written-V-spoken language things.  I don't even know how to be patronizing, I'm just a fragile drunk.  :)  I'll add mroe smilies next time.  This is twice this has happened.

Comment: (2) isn't really relevant. Yes, "twice" is a commonplace word, and more common than "two times", but that does not mean "two times" is uncommon, and certainly not that "two times" is wrong because nobody says that. [Learn It](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv304.shtml): "When it comes to **twice**, this is more often used than **two times**, although **two times** is also quite common in informal usage."

Comment: It's an outrageous piece of "opinionating", but +1 for *the pop song industry targets the lowest conceivable intelligence and educational demographic*. People do sometimes need to be reminded of such "truths".

Comment: “Been down one time / Been down two times / Don't let me down again.” (Lindsey Buckingham, 1973)