# Use of Thereof? "... feels like home, and a departure thereof"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I would really like to use a sentence like this in reference to a college. Not sure if the usage of "thereof" is correct (it doesn't sound like it) or if there is a better way to express this sentiment. Thanks

Comment: Methinks you want *therefrom*.

Comment: @PhilSweet Oh wow. I had no idea such a word existed. I guess at the risk of obscurity, I’ll use it. Thanks!

Comment: A very thoughtful and nice answer  Thank you for all the advice in both the grammar and the college search!

Comment: Best of luck, Anthony!

Answer (score 2):

Therefor, therefore, therefrom, thereof, therein, thereon, thereupon, and thereby are all perfectly correct words, but unless you're a 70 year-old lawyer, they're easy to misuse. Even when used appropriately they are unlikely to be consistent with the tone of the rest of your writing.  I'd like to talk you out of using any of them.

The purpose of a college essay is to allow the admissions officer to get to know you so he can decide whether you and the college are a good fit, with the ultimate goal that the college helps you prepare for the adult life you'd like to have. You help the college by growing and succeeding.  Everyone has strengths and weaknesses, things that are interesting, and ones that aren't, and you should own who you are.  More importantly, you should decide who you would one day like to be. It's probably not someone who sits at a desk all day writing contracts and wills that are chock-filled with "whereas", "inasmuch", and "thereof".

Writing an essay that gives the admissions officer the impression that you have a vast vocabulary, or, worse, that you are only pretending to, only hurts the chances of your finding the right college for you.  The more real you are, the more likely it is that you'll end up where you'll be happy and successful.

Go spend some time at a college campus and ask the students what they like or don't about the college. Ask what sort of people are happy there and what sort are sorry they're there.  You'd certainly be willing to answer those questions from someone who'd be going to your high school, and college kids are just as willing to help you.  Sit in on a freshman class.  You'll quickly find out if you'd be comfortable there, and motivated to work and to have some fun. Remember not to look for kids who are just like you, but rather look for kids that you think you'd like to become.  When you see it, you'll know.

Comment: That's sound advice about most of those words (although I might give more leeway for *therefore* than for the others). It's too easy to come off sounding... [Jacobean](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/231583/2085). :)

Comment: The danger with “therefore” is that it can be confused with “therefor”, but you’re right that it’s the least Jacobean and most visable member of the thereX family.